# How to round the number to a whole number using 0.5 rounds up in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

In my day-to-day job, there is a requirement to create a function that will take a number and return a string with the number format to a whole number with a minimum of 2 digits.

#### Here is the number of formatting steps and requirements.

```sh
    1. Counts/Units should always be shown in thousands.
    2. Take the number and divide by 1000. 
    3. Round the number to a whole number using 0.5 rounds up. If the resulting number is greater than or equal to 1000. use it. (this number should have a minimum of 4 digits)
    4. If not, round the number to 1 decimal point using 0.5 rounds up. If the resulting number is greater than or equal to 10, use it. (this number should have 3-4 digits)
    5. If not, round the number to 2 decimal points, using 0.5 rounds up. Use the number.
    6. Truncate any "0" at the end of the number after the decimal. Eg 0.20 should be displayed as 0.2, and 0.00 is 0.

    Examples
    1. 1,182,510 = 1,183
    2. 999,999 = 1,000
    3. 892,215 = 892.2
    4. 41,761 = 41.8
    5. 10,251 = 10.3
    6. 9,370 = 9.37
    7. 937 = 0.94
    8. 159 = 0.2
    9. 15 = 0.02
    10. 1 = 0.01
```

#### Here is my code so far :

```js
const nFormatter = ({ value, type = "number" }) => {
   //number
  if (type === "number") {
    // let num = (((value / 1000)*2)/2)  // Take the number and divide by 1000. 
    let num = value / 1000  // Take the number and divide by 1000. 
    let numRet = Math.round(num) //Round the number to a whole number using 0.5 rounds up
    if (numRet >= 1000) { // If the resulting number is greater than or equal to 1000. use it. (this number should have a minimum of 4 digits)
      return "$" + numRet.toLocaleString("en-US") // convert to K for number from > 1000 < 1 million
    } else if (numRet > 9 && numRet <= 1000) {
      return "$" + num.toFixed(1).toLocaleString("en-US") // if value < 1000, nothing to do
    } else if (numRet <= 9) {
      return "$" + temp.toFixed(2).toLocaleString("en-US") // if value < 1000, nothing to do
    } else {
      return "-"
    }
  }

}
```

#### Here is the tests

```js
const value1 =   1182510   //   $1,183
const value2 =   999999    //   $1,000
const value3 =   892215    //   $892.2
const value4 =   41761     //   $41.8
const value5 =   10251     //   $10.3
const value6 =   9370      //   $9.37
const value7 =   937        //  $0.94
const value8 =   159        //  $0.2
const value9 =   15         //  $0.02
const value10  = 1          //  $0.01


const test1  = nFormatter( { value: value1, type: "number" } ) 
const test2  = nFormatter( { value: value2, type: "number" } ) 
const test3  = nFormatter( { value: value3, type: "number" } ) 
const test4  = nFormatter( { value: value4, type: "number" } ) 
const test5  = nFormatter( { value: value5, type: "number" } ) 
const test6  = nFormatter( { value: value6, type: "number" } ) 
const test7  = nFormatter( { value: value7, type: "number" } ) 
const test8  = nFormatter( { value: value8, type: "number" } ) 
const test9  = nFormatter( { value: value9, type: "number" } ) 
const test10 = nFormatter( { value: value10, type: "number" } ) 

console.log(`value1 =  1182510   expected result:  $1,183 actual result: ${test1}` )
console.log(`value2 =  999999    expected result:  $1,000 actual result: ${test2}` )
console.log(`value3 =  892215    expected result:  $892.2 actual result: ${test3}` )
console.log(`value4 =  41761     expected result:  $41.8 actual result:  ${test4}` )
console.log(`value5 =  10251     expected result:  $10.3 actual result:  ${test5}` )
console.log(`value6 =  9370      expected result:  $9.37 actual result:  ${test6}` )
console.log(`value7 =  937       expected result:  $0.94 actual result:  ${test7}` )
console.log(`value8  =  159      expected result:  $0.2 actual result:   ${test8}` )
console.log(`value9  =  15       expected result:  $0.02 actual result: ${test9}`  )
console.log(`value10 =  1        expected result:  $0 actual result:    ${test10}` )
```

#### Here is the output

```sh
value1 =  1182510   expected result:  $1,183 actual result: $1,183
value2 =  999999    expected result:  $1,000 actual result: $1,000
value3 =  892215    expected result:  $892.2 actual result: $892.2
value4 =  41761     expected result:  $41.8 actual result:  $41.8
value5 =  10251     expected result:  $10.3 actual result:  $10.3
value6 =  9370      expected result:  $9.37 actual result:  $9.37
value7 =  937       expected result:  $0.94 actual result:  $0.94
value8  =  159      expected result:  $0.2 actual result:   $0.16 <--- Wrong
value9  =  15       expected result:  $0.02 actual result: $0.01  <--- Wrong
value10 =  1        expected result:  $0 actual result:    $0.00  <--- Wrong
```

#### ISSUE

Test 8,9, and 10 are wrong!

What I'm missing here?

Comment: I think you should split your code in smaller bits and use guard clauses instead of nested `if` statements. Maybe if your code wast just a tat bit more consice you'd find the error.

Comment: Thanks for response Fabio, would you please share more about "guard clauses instead of nested"

Comment: I will do that in a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I found the answer a few months back, but I will post it now.

```js
const nFormatter = ({ value, type = "number" }) => {
  //number
  if (type === "number") {
    let num = value / 1000  // Take the number and divide by 1000. 
    let numRet = Math.round(num) //Round the number to a whole number using 0.5 rounds up
    
    if (numRet >= 1000) { // If the resulting number is greater than or equal to 1000. use it. (this number should have a minimum of 4 digits)
      return numRet.toLocaleString("en-US") // convert to K for number from > 1000 < 1 million
    } else if (numRet > 9 && numRet <= 1000) {
      return num.toFixed(1).toLocaleString("en-US") // if value < 1000, nothing to do
    } else if (numRet > 0&&numRet <= 9) {
      return num.toFixed(2).toLocaleString("en-US") // if value < 1000, nothing to do
    } else if (numRet <= 0) {
        if (num === 0.001) {
            return 0.01 // if value < 1000, nothing to do
          }
        if (num <0.09) {
            return (Math.round(value/10)/100).toFixed(2).toLocaleString("en-US")
            
          }
        return num.toFixed(1).toLocaleString("en-US") // if value < 1000, nothing to do
      }else {
      return "-"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Previous context

I think you should split your code in smaller bits and use guard clauses instead of nested if statements. Maybe if your code wast just a tat bit more consice you'd find the error.

### Bad way

You should generally not (over)-nest if/else statements, they cause the code to be unreadable and very complex to understand. Guard clauses herby help you to make your code more concise.

```js
function userIsAdmin(user) {
 if (user.role == 'admin') {
  if (user.manager == true) {
   return true;
  }
  else {
  return false;
  }
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

### A better way

Guard clauses can reduce the number of lines in your functions, classes, and so on. A result of using multiple guard clauses is that you can see what conditions trigger certain code to be executed.

```js
function userIsAdmin(user) {
 if (user.role != 'admin') return false
 if (user.manager != true) return false
 return true
}
```